# PostgresSQL: Get single attribute of UDT in SELECT statement

Tags: postgresql, select, user-defined-type, composite-types

I created a user-defined type in a PostgreSQL 9.2 database and am trying in the `SELECT` statement to get only an attribute of the UDT. However, I don't seem to get my code to work.

Creation of type and table:

```
CREATE TYPE  ttp AS (f1 int, f2 int);
CREATE TABLE tbl (ctyp ttp);
```

The `SELECT` statement:

```
-- does not work
SELECT ctyp.f1 FROM tbl
SELECT ctyp(f1) FROM testtable
```

Both times I get an error. Is it possible to access a single attribute defined in a UDT in a `SELECT`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use:

```
SELECT (ctyp).f1 FROM tbl;
```

The parentheses are necessary to disambiguate tables from composite types as detailed in the [manual on composite types](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rowtypes.html#ROWTYPES-ACCESSING).

Comment: Thanks! The difference is very subtle. Btw, I thought it might be somewhere written in the manual, but I really couldn't find it. Thanks again!